# How to Migrate Project to Gradle

Tags: android, git, tfs

I have a project from TFS (Team foundation server) that I clone in Git and than import project through Version Control in Android Studio and when I run it, it keep saying that this project does not use the Gradle build system. (Migrate Project to Gradle) 
I looked for some solutions and I found that i need to delete .idea and .iml files from my root directory, but the thing is I should not delete those files because the whole team is working on the same project, yet the other members of team also use Android Studio and to them everything is working fine! 
How to solve this?

Comment: It seems that .ignore file is incorrect. *.iml files and .idea directory doesn't need to be in repository. To migrate project to gradle use _Import project_ wizard in Android Studio.

Comment: I deleted .idea and .iml files and import project again and everything is working now. Tnx

Comment: think you should read more about .gitignore [Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) example of Android gitignore file, [here](https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514) for Android Studio users. Useless files only increase size of your repository.